# How do I get last value before a delay expires, for each row, in Pandas time series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a time series with a single value A in Pandas. I want to generate a second column B which contains the last value before a certain delay (relative to the time of the original row) expires. The rows do not have a constant time difference. Is there a way to implement this efficiently in Pandas (or Numpy)? The data frame may contain multiple million rows and I hope that this operation takes at most a few seconds.

Here is an example:

```
time  A
10:00 10
11:00 20
11:05 30
11:15 20
```

Let the delay be 10 minutes. Then the result should be:

```
time  A  B
10:00 10 10    # In 10 minutes the value is still the same
11:00 20 30    # In 5 < 10 minutes, the value will have changed 
11:05 30 30    # Exactly, not less than 10 minutes
11:15 20 20    # Last row contains the same value
```

Edit: If there is no fast Pandas/Numpy solution, I will just code it in Numba. However, for some reason, my Numba solutions in the past to similar problems (nopython & nested for & break) were rather slow, which is why I am asking for a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do that. The key is the `searchsorted` function, that finds the insertion index of the delayed time value:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['10:00', '11:00', '11:05', '11:15'],
                   'A': [10, 20, 30, 20]})
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'] + ':00')
t2 = df['time'] + pd.to_timedelta('10min')
idx = df['time'].searchsorted(t2)
df['B'] = df.iloc[idx - 1]['A'].values
print(df)
#       time   A   B
# 0 10:00:00  10  10
# 1 11:00:00  20  30
# 2 11:05:00  30  30
# 3 11:15:00  20  20
```

Comment: This is great. Seems to perform very well!

For another use case, I will not be able to use the time, but instead will have to select for each row the value of the first following row which matches a criteria (like row.C < constant). Do you know by chance how this could be implemented in a fast way? I can open a new question if you prefer.

Comment: @JoelRichard Yes, maybe open a new question with a simple example, I think I understand what you mean but I'm not sure how I would do that to make it fast.

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you, I have opened the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381533/how-do-i-get-for-each-row-a-value-from-the-next-row-which-matches-a-criteria-in