# How do I get for each row a value from the next row which matches a criteria in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's assume we have a table like the one below:

```
A B
1 1.0
2 2.0
3 2.0
4 3.0
5 2.0
6 1.0
7 1.0
```

Now I want to get for each row the value from column A of the next following row for which B <= 2.0. The result is stored in C. Then we get:

```
A B   C
1 1.0 2
2 2.0 3 # Here we skip a row because next.B > 2.0
3 2.0 5 
4 3.0 5
5 2.0 6
6 1.0 7
7 1.0 Na
```

Is there a way to implement this efficiently in Pandas (or Numpy)? The data frame may contain multiple million rows and I hope that this operation takes at most a few seconds.

If there is no fast Pandas/Numpy solution, I will just code it in Numba. However, for some reason, my Numba solutions in the past to similar problems (nopython & nested for & break) were rather slow, which is why I am asking for a better approach.

Context: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376944/how-do-i-get-last-value-before-a-delay-expires-for-each-row-in-pandas-time-ser/57377674) I asked how I can get for each row in a time series data frame a value from the next row before a delay expires. This question is related, but does not use time/a sorted column and therefore `searchsorted` cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in just a few steps as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize column 'C' with the value of column 'A'
# for all rows with values for 'B' smaller than 2.0
# use np.NaN if 'C' if 'B' > 2.0
# because normal int columns do not support null values
# we use the new type Int64 instead 
# (new in pandas version 0.25)
df['C']= df['A'].astype('Int64').where(df['B']<=2.0, np.NaN)

# now just fill the gaps using the value of the next row
# in which the field is filled and shift the column
df['C'].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
df['C']=df['C'].shift(-1)
```

This results in:

```
>>> df
   A    B    C
0  1  1.0    2
1  2  2.0    3
2  3  2.0    5
3  4  3.0    5
4  5  2.0    6
5  6  1.0    7
6  7  1.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need slicing `df` on `B` less than or equal `2` and `reindex` and `bfill` and `shift`

```
df['C'] = df.loc[df.B.le(2), 'A'].reindex(df.index).bfill().shift(-1)

Out[599]:
   A    B    C
0  1  1.0  2.0
1  2  2.0  3.0
2  3  2.0  5.0
3  4  3.0  5.0
4  5  2.0  6.0
5  6  1.0  7.0
6  7  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: Don't use chained indexing.  Also this is just `df.A.where(df.B.le(2)).shift(-1).bfill()`

Comment: @user3483203: Thanks for comment. I agree avoiding chained indexing is a good practice on both reading and assigning. I updated the answer to avoid it. Using `where` is fine. I just wanted to try something different, so I used `reindex`